# click stop button to stop the moving seekbar and show seekbar to start position while playing audio

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I need to stop the moving seekbar on click the start button.And seekbar have to show in start position.

For that I tried, *seekBar.setProgress(0)* . But it is not working for me.Below I have posted the relevant code:

```
    public void stopPlay(View view) {
        try {

            if(myPlayer.isPlaying()){

                myPlayer.pause();
            }

            if (myPlayer != null) {
                myPlayer.stop();
                myPlayer.release();
                myPlayer = null;
                playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(false);
                text.setText("Recording Point: Stop playing");

                seekBar.setProgress(0);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Stop playing the recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
try {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
           seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }
   }); 
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```